# Composer autoload

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

Estou com problemas na hr de adicionar uma class ao meu autoload, fica dando Class Routes not found! Alguém poderia me ajuda?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Http\\Controllers\\": "app/Http/Controllers/"
    }
},
```

**Routes.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Routes {

    public function route() {
        return 'Ola';
    }

}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use App\Http\Controllers;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$route = new Routes();

dd($route->route());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só incluiu o *namespace* `Controllers`, então para utilizar a classe deste *namespace* você aind aprecisa referenciá-lo:

```
use App\Http\Controllers;

$routes = new Controllers\Routes();
```

Se você quer instanciar a classe sem precisar o *namespace* precisará incluir a classe ao escopo:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Routes;

$routes = new Routes();
```

Mas esta classe `Routes` é um controlador? Se está utilizando algo como MVC me parece muito estranho você ter essa classe dentro deste *namespace*.

Comment: Ainda n funcionou, ta dando Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Routes' not found. http://prntscr.com/n7nk4h